# extra solutions to radical equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

can someone explain why when a radical equation is solved some solutions don't work? Is there a rule when a certain transformation is performed on the equation it gives extra solutions? thanks very much

Comment: Your question does not only apply to radical equations. You will revisit this thought when you will study for example logarithmic equations, another fine chapter in precalc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps you may be used to for solving an equation are one-to-one. If all I know about $x$ is that $2x+1=0$, then

$$\begin{align}
&&2x+1&=0\\
&\iff&2x&=-1\\
&\iff&x&=-\frac12
\end{align}$$

Each step is an implication but so too would be the steps in the reverse order.

If all I know about $x$ is that $\sqrt{2-x}=x$ then I might start by squaring both sides:
$$\begin{align}
&&\sqrt{2-x}&=x\\
&\implies&2-x&=x^2\\
\end{align}$$

but already this cannot be reversed. To take the square root of the second line would leave us with $\sqrt{2-x}=|x|$, which is not what we started with. So the one-sided implication symbol can be used to emphasize that there is no going back. Continuing,

$$\begin{align}
&&\sqrt{2-x}&=x\\
&\implies&2-x&=x^2\\
&\iff&0&=(x+2)(x-1)
\end{align}$$

So we've found that if any $x$ at all satisfies $\sqrt{2-x}=x$, then it would have to be $-2$ or $1$. But of course, that has merely narrowed it down from infinitely many possible $x$-values down to two possible $x$-values. It's up to you do a little something more to actually solve the original equation.

Comment: thanks, it's much clearer now :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, when a transformation is [*one-to-one*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_function) (or *injective*), then it is reversible, so results in an equivalent equation. The problem with some radical equations is (for example) that $(-1)^2=1=1^2.$ That is, squaring both sides of a false equation (like $-1=1$) may result in a true equation, so we get extraneous solutions to deal with.

Comment: can you explain what is one-to-one transformation please?

Comment: Did you notice that "one-to-one" is a link?