# Solve $2x+(4x^2-3)^{1/2}=1$

Tags: polynomials

- $(1-2x)^2 = 4x^2-3$
- $1-4x+4x^2 = 4x^2-3$
- $x=1$

But $x=1$ does not work in the original equation.

Why does this happen? I appreciate both direct explanations and links to explanations, preferably on the general concept rather than this equation itself, thank you.

Comment: Why does what *happen*?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add a more detailed description.

Comment: Because you solved $$ \sqrt {4x^2 - 3} = 2x-1 $$

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597610/extra-solutions-to-radical-equations/597641#597641).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the first step you took --- squaring both sides. What happens if you take the square root of both sides of that equation? You don't get the original equation. Instead, you get
$$\mid 1-2x\mid = (4x^2-3)^{1/2}$$
which indeed has the solution $x=1$.

The fact that the only solution you got, $x=1$, is a bogus solution to the original equation indicates that the original equation has no solution, since squaring both sides can only add solutions, not remove existing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't happen because $(-a)^2=a^2$, so, by squaring the original equation, you allow for extra solutions to be added, some of which might not necessarily fit the bill.

Comment: In that case, there isn't a solution to the original equation?

Comment: Looks like it...